# Count good sets with given conditions

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, algorithms, permutations

We need to find the numbers of good sets in a sequence. The good set is:

A good set is a sequence of $P$ positive integers which satisfies the following 2 condition :

1. If an integer $L$ appears in a sequence then $L-1$ should also appear in the sequence
2. The first occurrence of $L-1$ comes before the last occurrence of $L$

**Example** : Let $P=3$ then answer is $6$

**Explanation** : The total number of output sets are $6$

One of the solution set is:

```
[1,1,1], [1,1,2], [1,2,1], [1,2,2], [2,1,2], [1,2,3]
```

For [$1,2,3$]= The first occurrence of $1$ comes before the last occurrence of $2$ and the last occurrence of $3$.

Comment: Hint : work out the the values of $f(1)$, $f(2)$, ... $f(6)$.  The answer makes itself known.  Proving is another matter though, I'm still working on that.

Comment: @DanielV What ? Is their any pattern ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to attack it:

Let $P(n)$ denote the number of *good* tuples of length $n$. Claim: $P(n) = n!$. Here is a  proof sketch using induction on $n$.

$P(1) = 1$, OK. Suppose it's true up to and including $n-1$. You can map each of the $(n-1)!$ good tuples of length $n-1$ to a unique good $n$-tuple as follows:

Let $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1})$ be a good tuple. For each $i=1,2,\ldots, n$ we augment $\mathbf{x}$ to $(x_1, \ldots, x_{i-1}, x*, x_i, \ldots, x_{n-1})$ by setting $x^*$ to be the largest value in $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ that keeps $(x_1, \ldots, x_{i-1}, x*, x_i, \ldots, x_{n-1})$ good.

For example:

$(1,1)$ gives 3 good tuples: $(\underline{1}, 1, 1), (1, \underline{2}, 1), (1,1,\underline{2}) $.

$(1,2)$ gives 3 good tuples: $(\underline{2}, 1, 2), (1, \underline{2}, 2), (1,2,\underline{3})$.

The extra bookkeeping is to:

1. show that these mappings are indeed good
2. show that these mappings are unique
3. show that if an $n$-tuple is not produced by this mapping, then it is not good

Here are the 24 good $4$-tuples that I found:

> [1, 1, 1, 1] [1, 1, 1, 2] [1, 1, 2, 1] [1, 1, 2, 2] [1, 1, 2, 3] [1,
>   2, 1, 1] [1, 2, 1, 2] [1, 2, 1, 3] [1, 2, 2, 1] [1, 2, 2, 2] [1, 2, 2,
>   3] [1, 2, 3, 1] [1, 2, 3, 2] [1, 2, 3, 3] [1, 2, 3, 4] [1, 3, 2, 3]
>   [2, 1, 1, 2] [2, 1, 2, 1] [2, 1, 2, 2] [2, 1, 2, 3] [2, 1, 3, 2] [2,
>   2, 1, 2] [2, 3, 1, 2] [3, 1, 2, 3]

Comment: (1) Is true by definition and the fact that 1 can be inserted into any sequence anywhere, and (3) could be established by showing the mapping is invertible, which is the same as "every sequence of length n has exactly 1 value that can be removed and result in a valid sequence, but increasing it would result in an invalid sequence"

Comment: I am curious how you found this mapping.

Comment: @DanielV, given the conjecture that $P(n) = n!$, it seemed natural to try to build good tuples inductively. So for each good $(n-1)$-tuple, one way to get $n$ new $n$-tuples is to try to fill in each of the available $n$ "slots". This is what resulted in the "max such that it's good" rule.

Answer (score -2):

When P=1, there is 1 good set.

```
[1]
```

When P=2, there are 2 good sets.

```
[1,1] and [1,2]
```

When P=3, there are 6 good sets.

```
[1,1,1], [1,1,2], [1,2,1], [1,2,2], [2,1,2], [1,2,3]
```

This pattern looks like it might be P!

Check if there are 4! = 24 sets for P = 4.

[1,1,1,1] ... [1,2,3,4]

Comment: This isn't really an answer, and would be better as a comment (with the redundancy of the information given in the question removed).  It is important not to post it as an answer so others know that the question hasn't been answered.

Comment: A bit harsh, I'd say. This COULD BE the answer. The redundant information was helpful and used very little space. This type of answer is what many are looking for. It's more of a hint or a "try this and see" answer that could lead the OP to a solution, or lead him to other helpful ideas. I don't mind if it is not marked as the accepted answer, but a downvote seems out of place.

Comment: @JLee, this would be better as an answer if *YOU* followed through and checked if there were $4!$ good sets for $P=4$, and then at least get started on the proof that there are $n!$ sets for $P=n$. Without this, your answer sounds like "maybe this is a good idea," which is better suited as a comment.

Comment: @mapierce271 Sometimes I choose to teach a man to fish, rather than give him a fish. The idea in my answer was right after all, and if the OP followed it, he might well could have done the proof himself. In the end, he would have learned much more than just reading the answer that someone else did for him. Many people don't want to be spoon-fed. They would rather find the answer.

Comment: Coming here in response to flags. JLee, your last comment is true. But your answer is written in a way that leaves open the possibility that you did not follow through with the induction yourself. I haven't done that myself either, but IMHO it is imperative the poster of a "teach a man to fish"-answer has done it themselves. Then the hint would be about how to come up with the inductive argument. I don't know for sure but the complains seem to be about your answer failing to be convincing in that sense.